# Weighted average values of overlapping polygons in python

Tags: geopandas, overlapping-features, summarizing

I am trying to reproduce the “[summarize within](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/big-data-analytics/summarize-within.htm)” ArcGIS Pro geoprocessing tool with GeoPandas.

I have basically two polygon files: one with socio-economic data in census units and one with income data in larger administrative units. My goal is to assign the income data values to the census units with taking the overlapping area as the weights. So if one census unit overlaps with 3 administrative areas, the calculated income for this census unit should be the weighted average of the income of the administrative units.

How can I calculate the overlapping areas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following logic with overlay:

```py
# store area size of census units
df_census['census_area'] = df_census.area
  
# create areas of intersection
df_is = gpd.overlay(df_census, df_income, how='intersection')  

# store the area size of intersections 
df_is['is_area'] = df_is.area # store the area size of intersections 

# ratio of intersection / whole area of census
df_is['ratio'] = df_is['is_area'] / df_is['census_area']

# weight by average
df_is['income_weighted'] = df_is['income'] * df_is['ratio']

# sum over census blocks
df_weighted_avg = df_is.groupby(['census_id'])[['income_weighted']].sum()
```